# Could not save recent table! phpMyAdmin #1062 - Duplicate entry 'root' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

So I made an EER diagram in workbench:
[image]

I then used forward engineer to create the database (Also tried script copy method)

It all seems to work fine but I constantly get this error in phpMyAdmin when I try to view any table:[image]

I tried exporting the database and importing, does not change anything.

Database backup:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.5.0.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Dec 03, 2015 at 05:45 AM
-- Server version: 10.0.17-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 5.6.14

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `mydb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tblattendees`
--

CREATE TABLE `tblattendees` (
  `AttendeeID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CompanyName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Suburb` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `State` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Postcode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Fax` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tblattendees`
--

INSERT INTO `tblattendees` (`AttendeeID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Title`, `CompanyName`, `Address`, `Suburb`, `State`, `Country`, `Postcode`, `Phone`, `Fax`) VALUES
(1, 'Stuart', 'Masia', 'Mr', 'M''Fees at Glebe', '234 Regent Drive', 'GLEBE', 'NSW', 'Australia', '2037', '02 9660 8856', '02 9660 8857'),
(2, 'Annie', 'Walker', 'Ms', 'Tuggeranon Eat House', '76 View Street', 'TUGGERANON', 'ACT', 'Australia', '0269', '06 4670 0023', '06 4670 0024'),
(3, 'Robert', 'Argyle', 'Mr', 'M''Fees Leichhardt', '19 Beauty Place', 'LEICHHARDT', 'NSW', 'Australia', '2040', '02 9662 3432', '02 9662 3433'),
(4, 'Hilde', 'Sorenson', 'Ms', 'Chatswood Deluxe', '301 Chalmers Street', 'CHATSWOOD', 'NSW', 'Australia', '2057', '02 9416 9092', '02 9416 9092'),
(5, 'Thomas', 'Williams', 'Mr', 'Rocklea Best Serves', '98 Argent Street', 'ROCKLEA', 'QLD', 'Australia', '4106', '07 6789 5693', '07 6789 5693'),
(6, 'Gary', 'Zheng', 'Mr', 'M''Fees Hazelvale', '467 The Esplanade', 'HAZELVALE', 'WA', 'Australia', '6333', '09 4563 6378', '09 4563 6379'),
(7, 'Natalie', 'Mylonas', 'Ms', 'M''Fees Picton', '6 Travers Lane', 'PICTON', 'NSW', 'Australia', '2571', '02 9566 4887', '02 9566 4887'),
(8, 'Manny', 'Reeves', 'Ms', 'M''Fees Lillyvale', '7/45 Market Street', 'LILYDALE', 'NSW', 'Australia', '2460', '02 9708 6541', '02 9708 6541'),
(9, 'Michael', 'Su', 'Mr', 'M''Fees Camden', '43 Lilly Pilly Avenue', 'CAMDEN', 'NSW', 'Australia', '2570', '02 9630 5851', '02 9630 5851'),
(10, 'Allan', 'Markson', 'Mr', 'M''Fees Brakendale', '4 Robertson Street', 'BRACKENDALE', 'NSW', 'Australia', '2127', '02 9720 7323', '02 9720 7323'),
(11, 'Kylie', 'Lee', 'Ms', 'Puchbowl Eat House', '22/118 Western Gardens', 'PUNCHBOWL', 'NSW', 'Australia', '2565', '02 9672 6574', '02 9672 6555'),
(12, 'May', 'Tucker', 'Ms', 'M''Fees Ruse', '37 Tulip Crescent', 'RUSE', 'NSW', 'Australia', '2560', '02 9860 7465', '02 9860 7465'),
(13, 'Greg', 'Higgins', 'Mr', 'M''Fees SA', '61 Sunlight Avenue', 'MILLICENT', 'SA', 'Australia', '5280', '08 7684 3324', '08 7684 3324'),
(15, 'Janine', 'Khoury', 'Ms', 'M''Fees Kellyvile', '55 Jamberro Street', 'KELLYVILLE', 'NSW', 'Australia', '2155', '02 9590 4874', '02 9590 4874'),
(16, 'David', 'Jones', 'Mr', 'M''Fees Western', 'P.O. Box 234', 'PARRAMATTA', 'NSW', 'Australia', '2150', '02 9768 7754', '02 9768 7755'),
(17, 'Tony', 'Marchant', '', NULL, '3 Grose St', 'Richmond', 'NSW', 'Australia', '2753', '02 45784455', ''),
(18, 'Kerry', 'Badopolas', 'Mr', NULL, '72 Kilcare Road', 'Blayney', 'NSW', 'Australia', '2799', '34343434343', ''),
(19, 'Rodney', 'Roberts', 'Mr', NULL, '4 Grose St', 'Richmond', 'NSW', 'Australia', '2753', '0299458888', ''),
(20, 'Charlie', 'Brown', 'Dr', NULL, 'Hight Street', 'Lithgow', 'NSW', 'Australia', '2794', '0268239000', ''),
(21, 'Bill', 'Hermatige', 'Pastor', 'Heavens Helpers', 'Hope Street', 'Outlooking', 'SA', 'Australia', '3345', '0398983343', ''),
(22, 'Clancy', 'Snow', 'Mr', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tblevents`
--

CREATE TABLE `tblevents` (
  `EventID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `EventName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Location` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StartDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `EndDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Confirmed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EventDesc` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EventFee` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tblevents`
--

INSERT INTO `tblevents` (`EventID`, `EventName`, `Location`, `StartDate`, `EndDate`, `Confirmed`, `EventDesc`, `EventFee`) VALUES
(1, 'McFees Asia-Pacific Zone Marketing Meeting', 'The Westin Sydney', '2005-06-26 00:00:00', '2005-06-30 00:00:00', 1, 'McFees annual conference', 350),
(2, 'Jones Insurance', 'Sheriden on the Park', '2005-08-01 00:00:00', '2005-08-03 00:00:00', 1, 'Jones Insurance half yealy Meeting', 320),
(3, 'Innovations Christmas Party', 'Captain Cook Cruises', '2005-12-20 00:00:00', '2005-12-20 00:00:00', 1, 'Work Christmas Party', 100),
(4, 'Innovations Christmas Party', 'Captain Cook Cruises', '2006-12-20 00:00:00', '2006-12-20 00:00:00', 0, 'Work Christmas Party', 200),
(5, 'Jones Insurance', 'Sebel Townhouse', '2006-01-25 00:00:00', '2006-01-25 00:00:00', 1, 'Weekend Escape', 650);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tblregistration`
--

CREATE TABLE `tblregistration` (
  `RegistrationID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `AttendeeID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `EventID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `RegistrationDate` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'This is the date and time the attendee registered for the event, or made the registration.',
  `RegistrationPaid` double DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'This is the amount paid for registration for an event.'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tblregistration`
--

INSERT INTO `tblregistration` (`RegistrationID`, `AttendeeID`, `EventID`, `RegistrationDate`, `RegistrationPaid`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, '2005-01-30 00:00:00', 350),
(2, 5, 2, '2005-02-02 00:00:00', 300),
(3, 1, 2, '2005-01-30 00:00:00', 320),
(4, 1, 3, '2004-12-15 00:00:00', 50),
(5, 3, 1, '2005-01-30 00:00:00', 150),
(6, 10, 2, '2004-12-12 00:00:00', 150),
(7, 4, 3, '2005-02-25 00:00:00', 100),
(8, 5, 3, '2004-08-17 19:29:10', 50),
(12, 15, 3, '2004-08-17 20:06:14', 100),
(13, 7, 3, '2004-08-17 21:12:41', 0),
(14, 16, 3, '2004-08-17 21:35:51', 0),
(15, 6, 3, '2004-08-17 23:03:07', 0),
(16, 12, 2, '2004-08-17 23:28:48', 0),
(17, 7, 2, '2004-08-17 23:41:50', 0),
(18, 2, 3, '2004-08-18 00:20:17', 0),
(19, 9, 2, '2004-08-18 00:21:20', 0),
(20, 8, 3, '2004-08-18 00:23:52', 0),
(21, 17, 3, '2004-08-18 09:28:08', 0),
(22, 13, 3, '2004-08-18 09:34:41', 0),
(23, 2, 1, '2004-08-23 10:43:38', 0),
(25, 11, 3, '2004-08-23 11:26:06', 100),
(26, 18, 3, '2004-08-23 11:26:27', 0),
(27, 19, 2, '2004-08-23 11:26:36', 0),
(28, 11, 2, '2004-08-23 12:09:41', 0),
(29, 20, 1, '2004-08-23 12:43:12', 0),
(30, 17, 1, '2004-08-23 22:10:13', 100),
(32, 21, 1, '2004-08-23 22:24:13', 350),
(33, 19, 3, '2004-08-23 22:31:11', 0);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tblstaff`
--

CREATE TABLE `tblstaff` (
  `StaffID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Mobile` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tblstaff`
--

INSERT INTO `tblstaff` (`StaffID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Phone`, `Mobile`, `Email`) VALUES
(1, 'Yin', 'Nguyen', '0297310273', '0415760088', 'johnsmirth@net.org'),
(2, 'Sandra', 'Jackson', '023204929', '041576089', 'CRAZYLADY@lady.org'),
(3, '', '', NULL, NULL, NULL),
(4, 'Stephen', 'Michaels', '0291283128', '0418586383', 'Stephanman@gmail.com'),
(5, 'Marie', 'Kukedis', NULL, '04156778', NULL),
(6, 'Robert', 'Maclean', NULL, NULL, NULL),
(7, 'Chantelle', 'Ross', '0297310286', '0455768904', NULL);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tblstaff_br_tblevents`
--

CREATE TABLE `tblstaff_br_tblevents` (
  `tblstaff_StaffID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `tblevents_EventID` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tblstaff_br_tblevents`
--

INSERT INTO `tblstaff_br_tblevents` (`tblstaff_StaffID`, `tblevents_EventID`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(1, 5),
(2, 3),
(2, 4),
(2, 5);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `tblattendees`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblattendees`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`AttendeeID`);

--
-- Indexes for table `tblevents`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblevents`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`EventID`);

--
-- Indexes for table `tblregistration`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblregistration`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`RegistrationID`,`EventID`,`AttendeeID`),
  ADD KEY `fk_tblregistrations_tblattendees1_idx` (`AttendeeID`),
  ADD KEY `fk_tblregistrations_tblevents1_idx` (`EventID`);

--
-- Indexes for table `tblstaff`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblstaff`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`StaffID`);

--
-- Indexes for table `tblstaff_br_tblevents`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblstaff_br_tblevents`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`tblstaff_StaffID`,`tblevents_EventID`),
  ADD KEY `fk_br_EventID_idx` (`tblevents_EventID`),
  ADD KEY `fk_br_StaffID_idx` (`tblstaff_StaffID`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tblattendees`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblattendees`
  MODIFY `AttendeeID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=23;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tblevents`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblevents`
  MODIFY `EventID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tblregistration`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblregistration`
  MODIFY `RegistrationID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=34;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tblstaff`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblstaff`
  MODIFY `StaffID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `tblregistration`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblregistration`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_tblregistrations_tblattendees_AttendeeID` FOREIGN KEY (`AttendeeID`) REFERENCES `tblattendees` (`AttendeeID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_tblregistrations_tblevents_EventID` FOREIGN KEY (`EventID`) REFERENCES `tblevents` (`EventID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `tblstaff_br_tblevents`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblstaff_br_tblevents`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_tblstaff_br_tblevents_EventID` FOREIGN KEY (`tblevents_EventID`) REFERENCES `tblevents` (`EventID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_tblstaff_br_tblevents_StaffID` FOREIGN KEY (`tblstaff_StaffID`) REFERENCES `tblstaff` (`StaffID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why there are no primary keys in your physical tables?

Comment: There are but it adds it at the end of the code strangely enough. ALTER TABLE `tblstaff_br_tblevents`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`tblstaff_StaffID`,`tblevents_EventID`),
  ADD KEY `fk_br_EventID_idx` (`tblevents_EventID`),
  ADD KEY `fk_br_StaffID_idx` (`tblstaff_StaffID`);

Answer (score 0):

So I restarted the computer, restarted xampp running as administrator, installed the services and checked phpMyAdmin again and the error is gone now.

Strange though that this error only showed for the databases created with the mysql workbench script and not others.